# Magento Sitemap Generate Problem

Tags: magento-1.9

When I go to catalog->google sitemap and Add Sitemap. The sitemap is generated succesfully.

But when I want to generate the same sitemap again it is not overriden. Or if I generate new sitemap with the same name its not updating sitemap. File is not updated. It is as it is created first time.

I think there is an override problem. Do you have any solution for this problem?

Magento V1.9

Answer (score 0):

You can't create 2 sitemaps with the same filename.

I don't understand what you mean with "File is not updated. It is as it is created first time."...

...every time you generate the sitemap magento writes newly all the file content.

You may have problems with sitemap file permissions or with it's parent directory permissions.

Make sure that the www-data (or httpd) user can write the file.